# Trying to remove the "hyperlink" of an username in a text formula field

Tags: formula

I have a username field that when it's on my page layout, it's text.  It is a standard text field, when I add that username "ex: user.user1@user.com" it shows it as a hyperlink.

I tried to build out a formula to cut off the "@user.com" to kill the hyperlink, and it doesn't work.

```
LEFT( username__c , FIND("@", username__c ) -1)
```

I tried to add a space between "." via a Substitute but the users want to have the Username LEFT of the "@" to show via text versus a hyperlink.

```
SUBSTITUTE(username__c, ".", " .")
```

I also tried to forgo the "." and break the username via a Substitute formula below with no true result (still hyperlink if there is a "." in the username LEFT of the "@" sign.

```
SUBSTITUTE( username__c , "@", " @")
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to a hyperlink appears at the rendering/UI layer, some time after the formula's been evaluated. This only happens in the UI, as well, not via the API, which always returns just the plain text. The only real way to avoid this happening is to render as HTML, which formula fields cannot do. If you were to create an HTML text field, and put the value in there, it should stay as plain text. I realize that this is overkill, but I don't know of a simpler solution.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I agree, it's weird because it's rendering different for different records...some are hyperlinked and some are not.  I don't think there is a way to remove it for every record....urgh.